# How to change baud rate of ttyS0 in Ubuntu 14.04?

Tags: ubuntu-14.04

I can't change the baud rate of ttyS0 and ttyS1 from 115200. I want to change the baud rate to 9600 because the baud rate of POS printer is 9600.

Answer (score 4):

The `stty` command handles that:

```
sudo stty -F /dev/ttyS0 9600
```

You can confirm that you succeeded in changing the baud rate by  asking `stty` to print out the current settings with:

```
sudo stty -F /dev/ttyS0 -a
```

See `man stty` for more details.